# C - Return 1 if any even-numbered bit in word x is set to 1

Tags: c, binary, bit, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I am stuck on a function that will return 1 if ANY even bit is set to one by only using ! ~ & ^ | + << >>.

So far I made my mask 0x55 (0101) so for example, 1110 (true) masked will return 0100 and 1010 (false) will return 0000. How do I express the answer so that the true will return 1 but the false will return 0?
Thank you very much
edit:
so far my code is:

```
int anyEven(int x){
   int mask = 0x55;
   return (x&mask);
}
```

Comment: Show what you have done.

Comment: `if(result > 0) return 1; else return 0;` or `if(result > 0) result = 1; return result;`

Comment: @FiddlingBits are there any other way to express that through the operators I listed above since I am unable to use if/else

Comment: @Clen Sorry, misunderstood.

Comment: Do you mean `return !!(x & mask);`

Comment: @Olaf editted my post to show my work so far

Comment: @M.M ah that was what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: Make the function `bool` and it is fine as written. Note, however, that you only check the lower 8 bits. There is no easy portable way to test all bits of an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int anyEvenBit(int x) {
    return 0 != (x & 0x55555555); // assuming 32-bit int
}
```